# Returning highest value in a column with certain header

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I nedd help with creating a formula in excel. I have two spreadsheets. In Sheet1 I have a table, names of the items in row 1, names of the parameters in column A and each pair of Item and Parameter has a value. In spreadsheet 2 I have a list of the same Items but in random order and with repetitions (Sorting is out of question as it would hurt formulas in other spreadsheets). I need a formula that for each Item in spreadsheet2 would return a name of the parameter with the highest value for that item. It looks very similar to the example on the pictures[image: sheet1][image: sheet2]

I was thinking about using something like `=INDEX(sheet1!A:A;MATCH(MAX(?);?;0);1)`
But in place of question marks I would have to put the column name in the formula or find a way to pass it a reference but I don't know how.

EDIT: I know how to do it in VBA but I would prefer to do it in a formula instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close, use another INDEX/MATCH to return the correct column:

```
=INDEX(sheet1!A:A,MATCH(MAX(INDEX(sheet1!A:S,0,MATCH(A2,sheet1!$1:$1,0))),INDEX(sheet1!A:S,0,MATCH(A2,sheet1!$1:$1,0)),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are tidier ways but here is an initial:

```
 =INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$12,MATCH(MAX(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$F$12, ,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$B$1:$F$1,0)+1)),INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$F$12, ,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$B$1:$F$1,0)+1),0))
```

[image: Sheets]

Comment: @pnuts.Sorry. Updated now.